# Проблема с break в for-цикле

Tags: python, циклы, for, pygame

Я перебираю список, который является инвентарем в моей игре. Каждый слот - тоже список, в который могут стаковаться одинаковые предметы. При выполнении функции, в которой добавляется предмет, происходит перебирание цикла, и если слот пустой, то в него просто добавляется предмет из обЪекта, с которого он взят (куст, дерево и т. п.). После этого я использую оператор break.

```
    if pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, natural_objects, False):  # Сбор с природных обЪектов
        obj = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, natural_objects, False)[0]

    if len(obj.items) > 0:          # Если обЪект не пустой
        for slot in inventory.slots:
            if len(slot) == 0:
                item = obj.items.pop(0)
                item.kill()
                slot.append(item)
                inventory.slot_alignment()  # Обновление позиций предметов, которые должны рисоваться
                print(inventory.slots.index(slot))
                break
```

По идее после первого попавшегося пустого слота, цикл должен завершиться, но если вывести содержимое инвентаря получим:

```
        for slot in inventory.slots:
            print(slot)
```

[<Item Sprite(in 0 groups)>]

[<Item Sprite(in 0 groups)>]

[<Item Sprite(in 0 groups)>]

...

Весь инвентарь заполняется одним предметом.
Вот от куда вызывается функция сбора:

```
 if e.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
        if e.key == pg.K_e:

            # Добавление предметов в инвентарь
            collecting_item(inventory, player, natural_objects, drop_items)
```

Я использую pygame.

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: А что не получается? Самое главное-то вы забыли написать..

Comment: А вы сделайте `print(len(slot))` и посмотрите, что там. Может вы не то что-то проверяете

Comment: Peter Kolosov, вроде написан break, а предмет почему-то добавляется в остальные слоты

Comment: CrazyElf,         for slot in inventory.slots:
            print(len(slot)). Вывод: 1, 1, 1, 1 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я сильно подозреваю, что изначально при создании `inventory.slots` вы делаете что-то подобное:

```
slots = [[]] * n
```

И в итоге у вас получается `n` раз ОДИН И ТОТ ЖЕ список, а не просто n одинаковых пустых списков. И когда вы делаете `append` одной из копий   списка, это отражается и на остальных копиях.

Если это действительно так, то просто вместо этого создавайте `inventory.slots` вот так:

```
slots = [[] for _ in range(n)]
```

Тогда у вас создадуться `n` действительно независимых пустых списков, которые не будут влиять друг на друга.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Это помогло